# Create my first Window 8 phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a 64 bit I3 Laptop with Windows 7 installed on it. I am an ASP.NET MVC developer and have solid understanding of C#.

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on my machine.

I wanted to try and develop windows 8 phone apps (just for fun).

My question is :

With the current configuration can I create a Windows 8 phone app ? I do not want to upgrade my laptop to Windows 8 (as it is an office laptop).

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: you can't, thank microsoft for that

Answer (score 4):

In order to develop for Windows Phone 8 you need Windows 8 64-bits and Visual Studio 2012. So yes, you need to upgrade or do it on a VM and an actual pone.

Comment: Thanks @danielrozo, on your point "or do it on a VM and an actual pone." please elaborate on this.

Comment: Create a virtual machine and install windows 8 with VS 2012 on it.

Comment: As Aviatrix says. I'd recommend upgrading if you don't have a phone, because debugging in the WP8 emulator requires a lot of resources and Hyper V